# How to increase the CPU and memory of docker container for Ubuntu VM?

Tags: docker, containers

I want to increase the memory limit to 30 GB and currently my CPU count is 4. I want to increase that as well. Docker update is not working in this

[image: Console memory]

Comment: Please describe your docker host. How much CPU and memory does it have? Are you running docker on Windows, Mac, or inside a VM?

Comment: Also, how are you running the container? What options, flags, config files, etc have you provided?

Answer (score 0):

Please check these [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) for more options on `--cpus` and `--memory`. Also your host system is having enough cpu and memory for this setup.